# An exercise related to properties of dedekind sums

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying assignment problems about properties of Dedekind sums and I am unable to solve this question.

[image]

I tried by putting qh, qk instead of h, k in definition of S(h, k) but I am only getting upto this S(qh, qk) = $\sum_{r modqk } [r/(qk) -0.5]((hr/k)) $ .  But I need to prove it equal to S(h, k) .

Can someone please help! !

Comment: What do the double brackets mean?

Comment: @The simpliFire -> ((x)) = x - [x] - (. 5 ) if x is not an integer, 0 if x is an integer.

Comment: @The SimpliFire it's also given on Page 61of Apostol's book if you have that.If you have any other doubt in question kindly ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
s(qh, qk) &= \sum_{r=1}^{qk-1} \left(\left(\frac{r}{qk}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{q-1} \sum_{r = mk + 1}^{(m+1)k-1} \left(\left(\frac{r}{qk}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{q-1} \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \left(\left(\frac{mk + r}{qk}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{h(mk+r)}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{q-1} \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \left(\left(\frac{mk + r}{qk}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \sum_{m=0}^{q-1}  \left(\left(\frac{mk + r}{qk}\right)\right)
\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \sum_{m=0}^{q-1}  \left(\frac{mk + r}{qk} - \frac{1}{2}\right)
\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \left(\frac{r}{k} - \frac{1}{2}\right)
\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \left(\left(\frac{r}{k}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right).
\end{align}
We are done.

Comment: except last 2 inequalities everything is understood. Can you please explain how you got last 2 inequalities from 3rd inequality.

Comment: @user795826   $\sum_{m=0}^{q-1}  \left(\frac{mk + r}{qk} - \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{r}{k} - \frac{1}{2}$. Note that $((x)) = x - \frac{1}{2}$ for $0< x < 1$. Thus, $\frac{r}{k} - \frac{1}{2} = ((\frac{r}{k}))$.